# Redis cluster via HAProxy

Tags: redis, haproxy, sentinel

I have a Redis Cluster that clients are connecting to via HAPRoxy with a Virtual IP. The Redis cluster has three nodes (with each node sharing the same server with a running sentinel instance).

My question is, when i clients gets a "MOVED" error/message from a cluster node upon sending a request, does it bypass the HAProxy the second time when it connects since it has been provided with an IP:port when the MOVEd message was issued? If not, how does the HAProxy know the second time to send it to the correct node?

I just need to understand how this works under the hood.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use HAProxy in front of Redis Cluster nodes, you will need to either:

1. Set up an HAProxy for each master/slave pair, and wire up something to update HAProxy when a failure happens, as well as probably intercept the topology related commands to insert the virtual IPs rather than the IPs the nodes themselves have and report via the topology commands/responses.
2. Customize HAProxy to teach it how to be the cluster-aware Redis client so the actual client doesn't know about cluster at all. This means teaching it the Redis protocol, storing the cluster's topology information, and selecting the node to query based on the key(s) being accessed by the consumer code.

With Redis Cluster the client *must* be able to access every node in the cluster. Of the two options above Option 2 is the "easier" one, but at this point I wouldn't recommend either.

Conceivably you could use the VIP as a "first place to get the topology info" IP but I suspect you'd have serious issues develop as that original IP would not be one of the ones properly being reported as a nod handling data. For that you could simply use round-robin DNS and avoid that problem, or use the built-in "here is a list of cluster IPs (or names?)" to the initial connection configuration.

Your simplest, and least likely to be problematic, route is to go "full native" and simply give full and direct access to every node in the cluster to your clients and not use HAProxy at all.

Comment: The Real Bill (not CLinton), i have already configured HAProxy and it is working fine with redis cluster. The only thing i need to know is - when a client gets a "MOVED" error/message from a cluster node upon sending a request, does it bypass the HAProxy the second time when it connects since it has been provided with an IP:port when the MOVEd message was issued?

Comment: As I said HAProxy doesn't know anything about Redis, so it will only proxy the data, it can not interact with Redis Cluster on an API level unless you teach it to. Your HAProxy, I can guarantee, is not "working fine with Redis Cluster", you just haven't seen the problems yet.

Comment: The Real Bill, so when a node in the redis cluster issues a "MOVED" message after receiving a request from a client intended for a hash-slot residing on another node, how does the client send know how to send it to the right node the second time around for the same request? And on the second request (after the MOVED message), does that request still have to pass through the proxy?

Comment: The Real Bill, what do you exactly mean when you say "..it will only proxy the data, it can not interact with Redis Cluster on an API level unless you teach it to"? Specifically, what do you mean by "API level"?

Comment: HAProxy is merely passing packets around, it has no idea of MOVED, SET, SADD, etc. so it can not take action on any of it. For the details on how the *client* must behave in RC, and what MOVED in particular does and who it has to be handled, see http://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec as it doesn't make sense to repeat it here.

Comment: i know that the proxy has no idea of these redis commands such as MOVED, SET, SADD etc. And i understand that the proxy currently holds no knowledge of the client and redis other other proxying requests and responses. But what i want to know is - Since when a MOVED message is issued to the client (of which an ip:port is also issued along), does that make the client bypass the proxy when issuing the same request for the second time since now it has the correct node's actual IP:Port provided by the node that sent out the MOVED message?